# print index and value if value is str in a numeric data type column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning, data-munging

I am new to data science and currently I'm exploring a bit further. I have over 600,000 columns of a data set and I'm currently cleaning and checking it for inconsistency or outliers. I came across a problem which I am not sure how to solve it. I have some solutions in mind but I am not sure how to do it with pandas.

I have converted the data types of some columns from object to int. I got no errors and checked whether it's in int and it was. I checked the values of one column to check for the factual data. This involves age and I got an error saying my column has a string. so I checked it using this method:

`print('if there is string in numeric column',np.any([isinstance(val, str) for val in homicide_df['Perpetrator Age']])`

Now, I wanted to print all indices and with their values and type only on this column which has the string data type.

currently I came up with this solution that works fine:

```
def check_type(homicide_df):
    for age in homicide_df['Perpetrator Age']:
        if type(age) is str:
            print(age, type(age))
check_type(homicide_df)
```

Here are some of the questions I have:

1. is there a pandas way to do the same thing?
2. how should I convert these elements to int?
3. why were some elements on the columns did not convert to int?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you very much

Comment: What is output of `print(age, type(age))` ? `NaN`s ? `non numeric`s ?

Comment: @jezrael all of which printed <class 'str'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
def check_type(homicide_df):
    for i, age in homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'].iteritems():
        if type(age) is str:
            print(i, age, type(age))
```

---

```
homicide_df = pd.DataFrame({'Perpetrator Age':[10, '15', 'aa']})
print (homicide_df)
  Perpetrator Age
0              10
1              15
2              aa


def check_type(homicide_df):
    for i, age in homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'].iteritems():
        if type(age) is str:
            print(i, age, type(age))

check_type(homicide_df)
1 15 <class 'str'>
2 aa <class 'str'>
```

If values are mixed - numeric with non numeric, better is check :

```
def check_type(homicide_df):
    return homicide_df.loc[homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'].apply(type)==str,'Perpetrator Age']

print  (check_type(homicide_df))
1    15
2    aa
Name: Perpetrator Age, dtype: object
```

---

If all values are numeric, but all `type`s are `str`:

```
print ((homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'].apply(type)==str).all())
True

homicide_df = pd.DataFrame({'Perpetrator Age':['10', '15']})

homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'] = homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'].astype(int)
print (homicide_df)

   Perpetrator Age
0               10
1               15

print (homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'].dtypes)
int32
```

But if some numeric with strings:

Solution for convert to `int` with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) which replace non numeric values to `NaN`. then is necessary replace `NaN` to some numeric like `0` and last cast to `int`:

```
homicide_df = pd.DataFrame({'Perpetrator Age':[10, '15', 'aa']})

homicide_df['Perpetrator Age']=pd.to_numeric(homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'], errors='coerce')
print (homicide_df)
   Perpetrator Age
0             10.0
1             15.0
2              NaN

homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'] = homicide_df['Perpetrator Age'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (homicide_df)
   Perpetrator Age
0               10
1               15
2                0
```

Comment: thank you very much! this solved my problem! checked it on every step. May I ask whether you know why some of the values did not convert to int when I converted the column? I used `df[['col1','col2']]=df[['col1','col2']].apply(to_numeric, errors = 'ignore')` method when I converted the columns

Comment: I think if use `errors = 'ignore'` it convert only numeric and non numeric are not changed. So get mixed `types` - ints with strings.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I am thinking 600 000 is huge df, for another data manipulation the best is create small data sample, use your code (easy verified output) and then apply solution to big dataframe. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the first time I used this much of data so I am still learning. I'll research on the best way to get a sample data from a large amount of data.